# Efficient way to give multiplicity count in TCL lsort

Tags: sorting, tcl

TCL lsort does not have the nice feature to provide a count of the multiplicity of items. Is there a speedy alternative? We're looking at lists ~1M objects with 100s of same entries.

```
blasort -unique -count { 3 2 4 3 1 }
1 : 1
2 : 1
3 : 2 
4 : 1
```

Thanks,
Gert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For counting the elements like that, it's much better to use a binsort-derived algorithm, with a dictionary or associative array as the fast map. The following should be efficient even with very large input lists:

```
proc countSort {elementList args} {
    set count {}
    foreach element $elementList {
        dict incr count $element
    }
    # Now sort the dictionary by the keys (i.e., the unique elements of the input)
    return [lsort -stride 2 -index 0 {*}$args $count]
}
```

Demonstrating how to use it by reproducing the output in your question from the input list you are using:

```
set input { 3 2 4 3 1 }
foreach {item count} [countSort $input] {
    puts "$item : $count"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Old fashioned using array ...

```
 proc count { lista } {
         foreach item $lista {
                incr counter($item)
        }
        return [array get counter];# return a list 
        ;# or showing the result 
        ;#parray counter 
   }
```